# Скачивание файла в memory stream c#

Tags: c#, передача-данных

Как скачать файл с Яндекс диска в memory stream. Много времени не могу найти информацию об этом.

Пытался как то так

```
            string token = "AQAAAABb39FLAAeXvhANBxjOrEkOrH8U7giSBSs";
            var api = new DiskHttpApi(token);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var link = await api.Files.GetDownloadLinkAsync("/" + folderName + "/" + "data.dat");

             }
```

Comment: так раз у вас есть ссылка, в чём проблема? `var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(link);` `var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`

Comment: нашёл, как ещё проще: `await api.Files.DownloadFileAsync("DiskPath", "LocalPath");`

Comment: await api.Files.DownloadFileAsync("DiskPath", "LocalPath"); сохраняет файл на компьютере в "LocalPath". А мне нужно чтобы в переменную MemoryStream

Comment: в первом коментарии я показал пример кода, с помощью которого можно получить данные в виде потока, за вас метод `ReadAsStreamAsync` автоматом создаёт новый `Stream` и возвращает его как результат. Если хотите, можете скопировать его в свой `ms` через `CopyTo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде ничего сложного, в крайнем случае можно [исходники](https://github.com/raidenyn/yandexdisk.client/blob/master/src/YandexDisk.Client/Http/Clients/FilesClient.cs) подсмотреть.

```
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
var link = await api.Files.GetDownloadLinkAsync("/" + folderName + "/" + "data.dat");
using var stream = await api.Files.DownloadAsync(link);
await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
```